# Randomly split a string at space (" ")

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to create two random substrings from a given string, which on joining will give me my previous string. How can it be done?

Example:
"My name is Robert" is the complete string, then substring can be like
    sub1:"My name"
    sub2:"is Robert"

Comment: Give example inputs and outputs to show exactly what you mean, and show what you have tried so far. Without those, we can't help.

Comment: What does your question title have to do with the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split at a random space, you can do something like this:

```
String str = "sentence with multiple words and spaces";

String[] split = str.split(" ");  // split string at every space

Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.nextInt(split.length); // choose a random space to split at

// Concatenate words before and after the random space
String first = String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 0, index));                 
String second = String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(split, index, split.length)); 

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);
```

Output of this will be something like:

```
sentence
with multiple words and spaces
```

or

```
sentence with
multiple words and spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will assign a random index bounded by the string length and then generate two substrings split at the random index.

```
Random rand = new Random();  // initialize Random
int index = rand.nextInt(str.length());                // get random integer less than string length
String sub0 = str.substring(0, index);                 // get substring from 0 to the random index value
String sub1 = str.substring(index);                    // get substring from random index value to end
```

Comment: Why are you using an explicit seed?

Comment: @shmosel habits I guess

Comment: @shmosel I removed it for simplicity's sake

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but you can't break the string at the middle of a word, just at spaces.@Dando18